# Using Calculate Field to fix hyperlinks in ArcPy gives Cannot use VB for services?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, vb

Getting an error while trying to script it, specifically "Cannot use VB for services."  Snippet and VB code block as follows:

Raw block (works within ArcMap): "\ftp\raw\YYYYMMDD\Files\Charles" +[NAME]+".ntf"

Snippet:

```
    date = '"20160207"'

    arcpy.CalculateField_management(outShp, "Link", '"\\\\ftp\\raw\\"' + date + '"files"' + "[NAME]"+ '".shp"', "VB", "")
```

Not sure what the issue is, somehow need to be able to insert the date and have it syntactically be correct (in either VB or python).

I didn't explain very well I have a column that contains a portion that is part of the hyperlink, so need to concatenate A column to the end of B column (with the partial path) to complete the link

Comment: USe r"............" syntax. Might work w python

Comment: Looks like in 10.1 it won't allow you to use VB for calculate field in python, although not entirely sure how to do it syntactically in python.

Comment: "Cannot use VB for services." - This error usually appears when trying to calculate fields using VB when you have background 64 bit geoprocessing enabled.  Turning off background geoprocessing should get you past this error

Comment: See if !name! Will work. Alternatively use python window on calculator and copy syntax from result window

Comment: Nothing for the !name!, I ran the calculate field tool with the VB syntax (it worked), copied the python snippet, pasted into my script exactly... and the exact same syntax is invalid

Comment: I think you should narrow the scope of your question to the VB or Python parser rather than both.  I think @Midavalo's [comment](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179813/trying-to-use-calculate-field-to-fix-hyperlinks-arcpy-cannot-use-vb-for-serv#comment270548_179813) explains the likely reason for the error.  Personally, I would use the Python parser.

Comment: The python parser accepts the syntax in the native arc tool, but I can't seem to translate it into the main script.  Here is the raw (working) syntax that functions with the tool


    "\\\\ftp\\raw\\" + "20160206" + "\\Win\\Charles\\" + !NAME! + ".shp"

Comment: Answer was posted yesterday [Here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/179990/60536) by @Berend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem sufficiently. As far as I got it, I would try the following:

```
# predefine the constant parts of your expression using a variable:
constant = "\ftp\raw\YYYYMMDD\Files\Charles"
nameVar = "yourobject.Name"

# use the built in function .format for setting up the expression for your arcpy.CaculateField_management function:
expression = """{0}\{1}files{2}.shp""".format(constant, date, nameVar)
arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("yourworkspace", expression)

# then simply use the expression variable in your arcpy function:
arcpy.CalculateField_management(outShp, "Link", expression)
```

If you want to put togehter paths and file names, you could look into the `os.walk` or `arcpy.da.walk` tool. Also, should there remain problems with the SQL-expression, try the `arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters()` tool. Hope this helps.

**Edit 9th of February 2016:**
Since you're saying that your syntax is working within the main tool but not in the script, I suggest checking your paths. Avoid gaps and special characters. Also try checking the *"store relative path names"* under the general tab of your script properties. Have you tried the `arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters()` function yet? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get the script translated to python would be to create a Model, here are the steps:

1. Create a blank model
2. Add the Calculate Field tool, fill out everything using the UI, run it
3. If it runs as desired export the model to python script, Model menu>Export>To Python Script.  The syntax should run in python for either the originally set parser (VB or python).