# Calculate Field throws an error when parsing python with backslashes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-parser

I have an FTP I need to access through a python script.  It works fine with forward slashes, but I don't need it to be read as an html. Below are both sets of code:

Working:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(outShp, "link", '"//ftp/raw" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + "/files/boundary" + !NAME! + ".shp"'
```

Invalid with backslashes:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(outShp, "link", '"\\\\ftp\\raw" + time.strftime(%Y%m%d") + "\\files\\boundary" + !NAME! + ".shp"'
```

Pretty new, but seems like it should work with the escapes, and does when used in the Calculate Field tool - just doesn't translate to my script.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: General invalid syntax

Comment: Please check your quotes, there seems to be one missing in strftime. Also, you could try to start the string constant with `r`, so you don't need escape sequences: `r'"\\ftp\raw" + etc`

Comment: Thanks, the quotes are correct in the script, just fat fingered it when I asked the question.  Fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work. Note that I use the `r` specifier for both the internal *and* external strings. You can skip the outer one, but then you need to double all backslashes.

```
arcpy.management.CalculateField("test", "Link", r'r"\\ftp\raw" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + r"\files\boundary" + !NAME! + ".shp"', "PYTHON")
```

Or, slightly longer, but with a more readable string format (less quotes):

```
arcpy.management.CalculateField("test", "Link", r'r"\\ftp\raw{0:%Y%m%d}\files\boundary{1}.shp".format(datetime.datetime.now(), !NAME!)', "PYTHON")
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, never even thought of using r for external as well.